# TypeError: User() takes no arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, google-bigquery, pycharm

class User:

```
def __int__(self, user_id, username):
    self.id = user_id
    self.username = username


user_1 = User("007", "Amul")

print(user_1.id)
```

output
[image]

in pychram
expected output should be : 007
but I got error {TypeError: User() takes no arguments}

Comment: `__init__` != `__int__`.

Answer (score 3):

That is just a typo. You've implement the **int** dunder method not **init**.

Comment: You should really just vote to close as typo, this exact question is posted every couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is not " int " but " init ".